# how to set the "|" character to last position in textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

on my filter, I remove invalid characters in my `textBox`, but after that I removed invalid  characters, the "|" is positioned into first position,how can I to set to last position?

For example:

current position:

123 **|** a <- invalid character, my function in the `_TextChanged` event remove it and the position go to:

**|** 123

I want:

123 **|**

I hope this is clear.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The | is called your cursor or caret position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `TextBox.SelectionStart` property to the end of the string, and the `TextBox.SelectionLength` property to `0`.

Something like this:

```
int textLength = yourTextBox.Text.Length;
yourTextBox.SelectionStart = textLength;
yourTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the SelectionStart to the current text length. In VB, this is:

```
txtStatus.SelectionStart = txtStatus.Text.Length
```

If this is a multi-line textbox or if the text exceeds the visible width of the textbox, you also may need to scroll the selection point into view:

```
txtStatus.ScrollToCaret()
```